# How do I add a MSTest unit test support to a C# application

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

How do I add MsTest support to an existing C# application project in VS2012?

I want to be able to add unit tests to the application project and have the IDE integration show the 'click to run' icons in the editor.

I do *not* want to have to create a separate project.

[Edit1]

For those who are interested this is trivially easy in NUnit and works 'out of the box'. If you have a large WPF application and want to be able to launch each UI Window from the IDE to preview or debug without having to run the entire application and navigate to the Window you want to view, then a simple inline test like this overcomes the lack of this basic feature in the VS designer.

```
#if DEBUG
    [TestFixture]
    public class MainWindowTests
    {
        [Test]
        [STAThread]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Application a = new Application();
            MainWindow w = new MainWindow();
            a.Run(w);
        }
    }
#endif
```

The NUnit support assembly reference can also be easily excluded for a release build using a conditional reference in the .csproj file.

(Support to run dialogs from the designer used to be a built in feature all the way back in Visual Studio 6, but like so many other useful features was lost as MS evolved VS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not fight against the way Microsoft has designed the testing framework - you need to create a separate project. Test projects contain a lot of stuff (e.g., references to the Microsoft test assemblies) that you do not want to be part of your application.

Comment: Looks like the answer to my question, although I think the answer to my problem will be to go back to using NUnit. I'd hoped MS had made MSTest a bit more useful by now, they've certainly had enough time to catch up.

Answer (score 4):

You *will* have to create a separate project, otherwise you'd only be able to run them in ReSharper (resharper will pretty much run anything you stick `[TestMethod]` on).

Comment: Actually you can run these tests in VS2012 IDE. Resharper is not required here.

Comment: I'm thinking that mstests can also still be run on the command line from the single project?

Answer (score 1):

In VS2017 using netcoreapp 2.0 (but I assume it will work with the framework) add these assemblies to the project from Nuget:

 `- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
 - MSTest.TestAdapter
 - MSTest.TestFramework`

Then any public method marked as [TestMethod] for any public class marked as [TestClass] can be run as a test in Visual Studio.